# How would I build pool-cues / simplified pinball-style plungers with SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm working on a game in which the user should be able to trigger 'rods' that come out from the edge of the screen to displace elements on screen (balls). These projectiles roughly resemble pool-cues. Or perhaps pinball plungers, except that they start from the 'loaded' position (mostly offscreen), and when triggered, they eject out, then quickly retreat.

I'm unclear how I should build these with Sprite Kit.

The game uses the PhysicsEngine, and the onscreen balls should be effected both by gravity AND they should be displaced when they collide with the rods. However the rods should neither be effected by gravity, not displaced when they collide with the balls -- they should simply retreat regardless of whether they've made contact with the balls.

I realize I can set the affectedByGravity property for the rods. However because they will still displace slightly when they collide with the balls. How can I 'fix' or 'peg' them in place? Do I need to use an SKPhysicsSlidingJoint? If so, has anyone encountered any examples online? Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A related physics engine, [Box2D](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082973) distinguishes *static*, *kinematic*, and *dynamic* bodies.
Kinematic bodies can move and will collide with other objects, but they are themselves not affected by dynamic bodies or forces like gravity. Thus, consider setting `rod.dynamic = NO;` but animate it with actions. See also [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/dynamic) in the reference for `SKPhysicsBody`.